# Can't remove items from the cart correctly (JavaScript & Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically, I have a cart that I recently upgraded to support product customization (at a very basic level). The upgrades included color and material type for a particular bike in addition to name, price, and quantity.

The problem is that since the new features that I added use combo-boxes or options, every time I add items to the cart with slightly different color and material combination if I attempt to delete the previously added combinations, it will only allow me to delete the newest one.

I feel this is easier to show in code than to try and explain it.
This is my logic for deleting items off the cart:

```js
//removing one particular item completely from the cart
AS_shoppingCart.removeItemAll = function(name, color, material){
    //for every item in the array which has the same name; remove.
    for (var i in this.cartShop)
        if(this.cartShop[i].name === name, this.cartShop[i].color === color, this.cartShop[i].material === material) {
            this.cartShop.splice(i, 1);
            break;
        };
    AS_shoppingCart.saveLocalCart();
};
```

For those who are interested, this is how I store the object instances on the array:

```js
//THE LOGIC FOR THE SHOPPING CART - OOP
var AS_shoppingCart = {};
//cart where the item objects will be stored
AS_shoppingCart.cartShop = [];
//item object and its properties
AS_shoppingCart.Item = function(name, price, quantity, color, material) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.color = color;
    this.material = material;
};
```

This is how my HTML looks like. Note, the problem is with these options. In order to delete older cart entries, I have to select the option combination the same as the listed item. Which logically makes sense, but the problem is, I haven't got the slightest clue on how to go around this problem.

```html
                 <div>
                    <h4>Customisation:</h4>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Color</th>
                          <th>Material</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>
                            <select id="colors" name="colors">
                               <option data-color="Default">Default</option>
                               <option data-color="Blue">Blue</option>
                               <option data-color="Green">Green</option>
                               <option data-color="Brown">Brown</option>
                             </select>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                             <select id="materials" name="materials">
                                <option data-material="Alloy">Alloy</option>
                                <option data-material="Steel">Steel</option>
                                <option data-material="Carbon Fibre">Carbon Fibre</option>
                                <option data-material="Titanium">Titanium</option>
                              </select>
                            </td>
                         </tr>
                      </table>
                   </div>
                   <div class="button-group">
                       <button class="add-to-cart" data-name="Aluminum road bike " data-price="256">Add to cart</button>
                   </div>
```

This is the jQuery part where it puts the logic into use. Note; I've cut out the irrelevant parts in the snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* CART */
        //assigning a click event to DOM object
    $(".add-to-cart").click(function(event){
        //prevents the page from being refreshed
        event.preventDefault();
        //sets the name variable to a clicked data-name
        var name = $(this).attr("data-name");
        //sets the price to the number version of data-price attribute
        var price = Number($(this).attr("data-price"));
        var color = $('#colors option:selected').data('color');
        var material = $('#materials option:selected').data('material');
      
    $(".add-to-cart").attr({
        "data-color" : color,
        "data-material" : material
    });
        AS_shoppingCart.addItem(name, price, 1, color, material);
        displayCart();
    });
    
    $("#show-cart").on("click",".delete-item", function(event){
        var name = $(this).attr("data-name");
        console.log(name);
        AS_shoppingCart.removeItemAll(name);
        displayCart();
    });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So my question is, how do I go about ensuring that I don't actually have to set my product item options to the older items in the cart in order to delete them.

Thank you.

EDIT: showing my addItem function:

```js
//adds items to the cart
AS_shoppingCart.addItem = function(name, price, quantity, color, material){
    /*checks to see if the item with the identical name exists in the cart
    if so, it will only increment the quantity of the said item (no redundancies)*/
    for(let item of this.cartShop) {
        if(item.name === name && item.color === color && item.material === material) {
            item.quantity += quantity;
            this.saveLocalCart();
            return;
        };
    };
   var item = new this.Item(name, price, quantity, color, material);
    this.cartShop.push(item);
    this.saveLocalCart();
};
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better and safer to handle it server side? You delete item, then you reload cart content.

Comment: This website is never going to be live. It's only for educational purposes. Sorry, forgot to mention it in the post.

Comment: Can you show addItem function? Can we have a fiddle?

Comment: Sure @sniels , I'll add it in the post.

Comment: Doing it server side, it allows you to use unique IDs, so that it is not difficult to find the wanted item to be removed. If you do it client side, you should develop a similar way to do this (in my opinion). I would create a unique id for each item, then it will be easy to find it in your cart array

Comment: @Yuri I probably would if I wasn't a complete newb.

Comment: Actually, your code seems to work correctly https://jsfiddle.net/f3s3o7zn/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because you use `break` after finding first item in cart.
Remove it to keep on iterating through items after finding first of it.

***UPDATE 2***

Also splice will provide change of items count so you better to reverse loop and delete items from last to first or simply use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) like this:

```
  //now items store shopcart with all items except those you want to remove
  //so you can store it back to this.cartShop or pass to another method to save new version of shopcart which is more acceptable way

  let items = this.cartShop.filter(function(item) => {
    return (item.name !== name && 
           item.color !== color && 
           item.material !== material)
  }
```

So your final code can be like this:

```
AS_shoppingCart.removeItemAll = function(name, color, material){

      this.cartShop = this.cartShop.filter(function(item){ return !(item.name === name && item.color === color && item.material === material) });

      AS_shoppingCart.saveLocalCart();
};
```

Comment: Hi, I'm having a bit of trouble understanding your code. When I implement your code, it simply returns an empty cart. Why do you want to return items whom name is not equal to the item being affected?

Comment: sorry, it must be like this (updated answer). i return items that color,name and material are not equal to values provided to a function.

Comment: finally got it, sorry, my fault. I filter out the items we need to delete and keep the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use splice in javascript...

for example:

```
//removing from the quantity
AS_shoppingCart.removeItem = function(name, color, material){
    //for every item object in the cart
    for (let item of this.cartShop) {
        //check if the name matches and remove from qunatity if true.
       if(item.name === name && item.color === color && item.material === material) {
           item.quantity --; // change this to -> name_of_your_array.splice(index, howmany);
           this.saveLocalCart();
           //once the quantity reachers 0 or below, completely remove the item from cart.
           if(item.quantity === 0 || item.quantity < 0) {
               this.removeItemAll(item.name, item.color, item.material); // change this to -> name_of_your_array = [];
               this.saveLocalCart();
           };
           break;
       }; 
    };
    this.saveLocalCart();
};
```

I'm still not sure though, in my case before I was just using array. But definitely you can use splice. :)

Comment: Ah yeah, I linked the wrong part of code. This is basically for decrementing the quantity, not strictly item deletion. The removeItemAll() method indeed uses splice.